# Log PHP-script that take long time to render

Tags: php, logging, debugging

I would like to find out, which pages on my server are really slow.

Is it possible to log all pages that took longer than 2 seconds to render in a file?

```
/var/log/php/php-slow.log
```

Or could the information about the time it took to render be added to the apache-log-files?

Comment: You could write a script that you setup with `auto_prepend_file`.  Log the time at script start, and then setup something to log the time the script finishes with `register_shutdown_function`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using Apache; see this Stack Overflow answer: [Is there a way to have Apache log slow requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3878700/69683)

To blatantly steal  [bradym](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205481/bradym)'s answer (thankyou [cc-wiki](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)):

---

Take a look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html. You can setup a custom log that includes the time it took to serve the request.

For example:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %D" common-time
```

Would add the time in microseconds it took to serve the request as the last field of your logfile.

You would add that line to your httpd.conf, then in each virtualhost where you want to use it, add this line:

```
CustomLog logs/access_log_time common-time
```

You could also create a new LogFormat that contains only exactly what you want, maybe like this:

```
LogFormat "\"%r\" %D" measure-time
```

In your virtualhost, you can have multiple logs, so you could have:

```
CustomLog logs/access_log common
CustomLog logs/access_log_time measure-time
```

All that said, there's a **huge caveat**. This will measure only the time it takes the server to serve the page. It **will not** include the time it takes to execute any javascript in the browser. If you need to measure javascript execution time, you'll need to use a tool like [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Once you've got the log, you could use something like [apachelog](https://github.com/nickmoorman/apachelog) to parse the logfile to get only the requests that took longer than whatever threshold you want to use.

I'm not sure if it's possible to log only the log requests and bypss the parsing step. It might be, but i have a feeling it would take a significant amount of work.

Comment: Thanks! That `%D` was exactly what I was looking for. But how do I find the slowest calls now within my 250 different apache-logs for each host?

Comment: By analysing them of course. Get the data out of their text files and into a spreadsheet or an SQL database. Then you can do whatever you want with them. They're space delimited, so opening them in say Excel shouldn't be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

[PHP slow logging](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#slowlog) is only supported with [the FPM SAPI](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php).

Comment: Can I simply enable this on my server?

Comment: Since you have a web host with 250 users... no, it won't be simple at all.